# How do I translate this SQL to ecto query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I translate this SQL to ecto query

```
SELECT * 
 FROM table_name
 WHERE table_name.the_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

without using fragment.

This works for me but I am wondering is there is a ecto idiomatic way to do this kind of query.

```
iex(22)> query = from n in Table,
...(22)> where: fragment("updatedAt > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"),
...(22)> select: n;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite it to this:

```
from t in Table,
where: t.updatedAt > datetime_add(^Ecto.DateTime.utc, -1, "day")
```

The docs are [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#datetime_add/3)